# Mysql i get Error when i try to edit after insert data

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

this is my one of database table structure and after insert some fields as row into that i can't update columns and i get error:

```
CREATE TABLE `channels` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `channelName` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `channelLink` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `channelDescription` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `channelImageFileName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `channelAvatarFileName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `channelState` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `channelType` enum('channels','userCreatedChannels') COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `channelOwnerUserId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fileServerUrlId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `channels`
--
ALTER TABLE `channels`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Error and notice:

```
This table does not contain a unique column. Features related to the grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete links may not work after saving.
```

Error

```
UPDATE `channels` SET `channelState` = '1' WHERE  LIMIT 1

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1
```

`id` of this table is unique and `A_I`, how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: Remove `WHERE`.

Comment: @Cthulhu `where` generated by `phpmyadmin` i dont write this command

Comment: remove `WHERE  LIMIT 1`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza please read my last comment

Comment: well, your command is wrong. `WHERE` need a condition expression like `WHERE channelState = '5'`

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?